# Auto-generated code in Visual Studio 2013. Header and source files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

My team and I are starting a game project in C++. According to our professor, header files should only include interfaces, and source (.cpp) files should contain the implementation of our code found in our header file. However, after fooling around in Visual Studio, I noticed that the auto-generated code, say for a button click, is thrown in the header file with a body ready to implemented.

**Game.h**

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
```

Where I would have expected it to be:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
```

And then implement it in our source file.

**Game.cpp**

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // Code here
}
```

Is there a reason why this is done like this? Must I really modify the code in order to follow proper standards of separation between interface and implementation?

Comment: Not sure how your professor expects templates to work without putting them into an include file to make them available to any source file needing the template.

Comment: If you want to follow your professor, which would probably be a good thing to do if you want passing marks, you can just manually change the .h file and replicate the definition, the actual body of the function, in your .cpp file.  The C++ compiler does not care.

Comment: @RichardChambers this is what I've been doing so far; removing the bracket body from methods from the header file and adding code in the source file by replicating the method... I'll have to discuss this with him...

Comment: It looks like you are using .NET C++/CLI with managed C++ so that might be part of why the Microsoft wizard is generating that source code style. There can be many cases where a handler is just a line or two of source so many times it is easier to just put the method definition body into the class declaration. The primary reasons for not putting implementation into the include file is to reduce recompiles with changes or to hide implementation details that are secrets of one kind or another. It sounds like your professor wants you to start with good programming habits.

Comment: One problem you may run into is that changing the auto generated may result in the wizards not working properly.  What I have found is that they can be fairly flexible, Microsoft seems to have come a long way since Visual Studio 6, but you can break them by moving source around. The result will be that future changes may need to be done by hand without using the wizards themselves. The good side of that is that you get to learn gory details that the wizards hide!!

Comment: The pragmatic solution to deal with your immediate problem (the dogmatic professor): Use MFC. The [MFC Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520.aspx) generates code, that is to your professor's liking. If nothing else, it'll give you a chance to see him/her go bananas about **heavy** macro use. That, and it'll solve your other problem: MFC **is** C++ (well, sort of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple way the limit the amount of hassle you have to deal with when you modify the UI design.  Adding a new event handler is pretty straight-forward, the trouble starts when it needs to be removed again.  Say when you remove the button from the window.

The way it is done now, code is generated in only two places, the InitializeComponent() method and the Click event handler method itself.  Removing the event is simple, the designer just removes the statement in InitializeComponent() and you will not lose any code you've written in the Click event handler.  And it is simple to rescue or abandon any code you've written, you just copy/paste and delete the method.  Either way, the project still compiles.

Lots more hassle with code generated in three places.  Neither deleting the declaration in the .h file and having the project not compile anymore nor deleting any code you've written in the method are attractive choices.

Absolutely nothing to fret about, simply move the method body into the .cpp file if that's you're preference.  You do this when the design is stable.  Or not at all because it works just fine as-is.

Comment: Worth noting: When writing managed code in C++/CLI, a header file is an artifact, that's not at all needed. The assembly contains all the meta information needed to consume any exported type.

Comment: It is not nearly that simple, metadata can only work when one project references another.  The .h file is still needed when an assembly contains multiple UI classes and they interact with each other.  As they usually do.  The compilation model of C++ (single-pass, separate TUs with a linker) keeps them relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant In other words, the way it is done right now is fine as-is. I just realized that the InitializeComponent() also had body with all the different UI events etc. I guess this is a matter of preference, of course made by our prof...

Comment: @Dimitri: You are still missing a vital piece of information: You aren't writing C++ code, but C++/CLI code. C++/CLI is related to C++, but a completely different language. If you want to write C++, create a Win32 C++ project. Bear in mind, that there won't be any auto-generated code. With C++, you're on your own. Unless you use a library, like MFC.

Comment: @IInspectable I see. So in order to write pure c++ code with some basic GUI and Windows forms, MFC would be the way to go? The goal is for us to have complete control of what will go in and out in terms of libraries and code...

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the auto generation is Visual Studio did is correct in terms of being able to compile. However, what your professor instructed is more conventional.